# How to create Ext js widget with Ext.draw.engine.Canvas as an item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, extjs, sencha-architect

I want to create widget using Ext js, in which one item should be a canvas.

When I am trying to add an item as `xtype: 'canvas',` I am getting following error.

```
Ext.Loader is not enabled, so dependencies cannot be resolved dynamically.
Missing required class: tree {stack: (...), 
message: "Ext.Loader is not enabled, 
so dependencies cannot …esolved dynamically. 
Missing required class: tree", 
isInstance: true, $className: "Ext.Base", configClass: function…}
```

Following is my code snippet:

```
Ext.widget({
        xtype   : 'mz-form-widget',
        itemId: 'shopableImage',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'canvas',
                width: 750,
                height: 470,
                itemId: 'preview-container'
            }
        ],
```

How can I include a canvas item into my widget panel?
Whats I am missing over here?

Comment: Are you including the draw package in your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canvas does not have an alias (xtype) defined, so you cannot configure it inline as above. You can either create it explicitly with `Ext.create` or you can go to an upper-level component such as `Surface` or `Ext.draw.Container`.